# Error When trying to use XSSF on Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, apache-poi, beanshell, xssf, hssf

I am getting error when trying to create **xlsx** file using Jmeter. actually I already try using **HSSF** (for .xls) and it is works fine. But when I am trying to change it using **xlsx**, I am getting error. I already copy the jar file for **poi** and **poi-ooxml** on jmeter **lib** file. here is my simple script :

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.Object;

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("HENCIN");

try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Jmeter\\testhencin.xlsx"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Actually when I am trying to find the error, the problem are getting from this line :

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");
```

Please someone help me to figure it out. it works on **HSSF** but on **XSSF** it is not working. I am getting error :Response code: 500

```
Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject
```

Comment: Did you [copy in all the Apache POI dependencies as handily listed on this page on the site](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)? If not, what happens when you read the docs and do so?

Comment: yeah... I still missing some dependencies. now it works like a charm. I use this : poi-3.11.jar , poi-excelant-3.11.jar, poi-ooxml-3.11.jar , poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11,jar , poi-scratchpad-3.11.jar, xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

1. Catching all the possible exceptions and printing the stacktrace to jmeter.log file as well
2. Re-throwing the exception to make sure you won't get false positive sampler result, something like:

   ```
   } catch (Throwable e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       log.info("Error in Beanshell", e);
       throw e;
   }
   ```

With regards to your question, most likely it is due to missing [XMLBeans](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/) jar in [JMeter classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath). I would suggest the following:

- Get "clean" installation of the latest JMeter version
- Download the latest version of [tika-app.jar](https://tika.apache.org/download.html) and drop it to JMeter's "lib" folder
- Restart JMeter to pick the jar up

Using Tika you will get all the necessary libraries bundled, moreover, you JMeter will display content of the binary files in the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. See [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-extract-data-files-jmeter) article for more details.